# Как отловить событие закрытия окна через «крестик» в fyne?

Tags: windows, golang

Есть *GUI*-приложение. Задача: как только пользователь решил закрыть приложение, спрятать окошко и доделать работу, после чего спокойно умереть. В качестве фреймворка использую `fyne.io/fyne`.

Answer (score 1):

Я Вам крайне не рекомендую использовать fyne. Соберите приложение с опцией -race и Вы сильно удивитесь.

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь за некрокомментинг, но у меня была похожая ситуация, которая решилась с помощью `defer function()` без всяких отловов событий.